# Check for any other value in a string than the ones from a list in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a calculated column in table1, that returns a string with several values in it. Each of these values represents a fault code and its format is DI followed by 4 digits.
Now I have a second table (table2) that has a list of faults codes, some of those fault codes can be found in the string of the calculated column from the 1st table.
What I'm looking for is a measure that will return a 'True' statement if any row from the calculated column in the table1 has a fault code that is not on the list of fault codes from table2. Additionally will return a 'False' statement in case of all codes from the string of calculated column in table1 are present on the list of table2. Please see a simplified example

[image] .

The result should look as follow

[image].

So far I've managed to check if only the first value from the string in the calculated column of table 1 fulfils that condition. Unfortunately, I'm not able to apply it to the full string, Could someone support, please.

Table2 list

```
| List   |
|--------|
| DI0001 |
| DI0002 |
| DI0003 |
| DI0004 |
| DI0005 |
| DI0006 |
| DI0007 |
| DI0008 |
| DI0009 |
| DI0011 |
| DI0013 |
| DI0015 |
| DI0105 |
| DI0107 |
| DI0108 |
| DI0211 |
| DI0212 |
| DI0505 |
| DI0806 |
| DI0907 |
| DI1113 |
| DI1212 |
| DI1504 |
| DI1505 |
| DI1601 |
| DI1602 |
| DI1603 |
| DI1604 |
| DI1605 |
| DI1606 |
| DI1607 |
| DI1608 |
| DI1609 |
| DI1610 |
| DI1611 |
| DI1612 |
| DI1613 |
| DI1614 |
| DI1615 |
| DI1616 |
| DI1617 |
| DI1618 |
| DI1701 |
| DI1702 |
| DI1703 |
| DI1704 |
| DI1705 |
| DI1706 |
| DI1707 |
| DI1708 |
| DI1801 |
| DI1802 |
| DI1803 |
| DI1804 |
| DI1901 |
| DI1902 |
| DI1903 |
| DI1904 |
| DI1905 |
| DI2601 |
| DI9901 |
| DI9902 |
| DI9903 |
| DI9904 |
| DI9905 |
| DI9906 |
| DI9907 |
| DI9908 |
| DI9909 |
| DI9910 |
| DI9911 |
| DI9912 |
| DI9913 |
```

Here is table1 and the calculated column

```
| Calculated   Column                                       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| DI0501 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1605 DI1604                                             |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1010 DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                               |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI1604 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604        |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 |
| DI0204                                                    |
| DI1015 DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                               |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 |
| DI1102 DI1605                                             |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI1604                                      |
| DI1605 DI1604 DI1010                                      |
| DI0107                                                    |
| DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1604 DI0204                                             |
| DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a measure like this

```
Measure =
VAR _1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( table1, "new", SUBSTITUTE ( table1[Calculated column], " ", "|" ) )
VAR _2 =
    GENERATE (
        _1,
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [new] ) ),
            "_txt", TRIM ( PATHITEM ( [new], [Value], TEXT ) )
        )
    )
VAR _filt =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _2,
        "score",
            VAR _1 = [_txt]
            VAR _2 =
                CALCULATE ( MAX ( table2[List] ), TREATAS ( { _1 }, table2[List] ) )
            RETURN
                IF ( _2 = BLANK (), "x", _2 )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        COUNTX ( FILTER ( _filt, [score] = "x" ), [Calculated column] ) >= 1,
        TRUE,
        FALSE
    )
```

[image: S1]

Comment: I forgot to mention some cells might be blank in the Calculated column, because of that the result is coming with an error 'The arguments in GenerateSeries function cannot be blank.' . I've tried the following ```IFERROR( IF (
        COUNTX ( FILTER ( _filt, [score] = "x" ), [Calculated column] ) >= 1,
        TRUE,
        FALSE
    )," ")``` But it coming with the following 'Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns.' Help please

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my end. Can you provide some sample data representative of the calculated column which generates the error on your side. Please provide the data in table format and not picture [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: Added a sample of requested data in my primary question

Comment: Are you trying to create a calculated column/measure? It working fine at my end with a measure and the revised dataset.

Comment: Ok so I have used the sample data in a new model and it works. However, it doesn't work for my original model. The only difference is that the Calculated column is a result of a measure, could this somehow influence the outcome?

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer. If the column (not a measure) exists (original/calculated) the solution I provided will work.

Comment: Your solution is correct for what I've asked, that is why well deserved acceptance of the answer.  Unfortunately, I'm new at power BI and I have used the wrong terminology in my question. Anny chance you could provide a solution if the Calculated column is a measure?

Comment: Can you please post that question in another thread please. Also if possible create a pbix in small scale which is is an exact representation of your issue and call me back by putting a comment here.

Comment: Hi,I;ve posted a second question with a link to a model, thanks fro help in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433437/check-for-values-from-list-in-a-string-from-a-measure