# Check for values from list in a string from a measure

Tags: powerbi

I have a Calculated column in table_1 which is a result of a measure that returns a string with several values in it. Each of these values represents a fault code and its format is DI followed by 4 digits.
Now I have a second table (table_2) that has a list of faults codes, some of those fault codes can be found in the string of the calculated column from the 1st table.
What I'm looking for is a measure that will return a 'True' statement if any row from the calculated column in the table1 has a fault code that is not on the list of fault codes from table2. Additionally will return a 'False' statement in case of all codes from the string of calculated column in table1 are present on the list of table_2. Please see a simplified example

[image] .

The result should look as follow

[image].

So far I've managed to check if only the first value from the string in the calculated column of table 1 fulfils that condition. Unfortunately, I'm not able to apply it to the full string, Could someone support, please.

Table2 list

```
| List   |
|--------|
| DI0001 |
| DI0002 |
| DI0003 |
| DI0004 |
| DI0005 |
| DI0006 |
| DI0007 |
| DI0008 |
| DI0009 |
| DI0011 |
| DI0013 |
| DI0015 |
| DI0105 |
| DI0107 |
| DI0108 |
| DI0211 |
| DI0212 |
| DI0505 |
| DI0806 |
| DI0907 |
| DI1113 |
| DI1212 |
| DI1504 |
| DI1505 |
| DI1601 |
| DI1602 |
| DI1603 |
| DI1604 |
| DI1605 |
| DI1606 |
| DI1607 |
| DI1608 |
| DI1609 |
| DI1610 |
| DI1611 |
| DI1612 |
| DI1613 |
| DI1614 |
| DI1615 |
| DI1616 |
| DI1617 |
| DI1618 |
| DI1701 |
| DI1702 |
| DI1703 |
| DI1704 |
| DI1705 |
| DI1706 |
| DI1707 |
| DI1708 |
| DI1801 |
| DI1802 |
| DI1803 |
| DI1804 |
| DI1901 |
| DI1902 |
| DI1903 |
| DI1904 |
| DI1905 |
| DI2601 |
| DI9901 |
| DI9902 |
| DI9903 |
| DI9904 |
| DI9905 |
| DI9906 |
| DI9907 |
| DI9908 |
| DI9909 |
| DI9910 |
| DI9911 |
| DI9912 |
| DI9913 |
```

Here is table1 and the calculated column

```
| Calculated   Column                                       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| DI0501 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1605 DI1604                                             |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1010 DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                               |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI1604 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604        |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1604 DI1605                                             |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 |
| DI0204                                                    |
| DI1015 DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                               |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 |
| DI1102 DI1605                                             |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI1604                                      |
| DI1605 DI1604 DI1010                                      |
| DI0107                                                    |
| DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1604 DI0204                                             |
| DI0105 DI1604 DI1605                                      |
| DI1605                                                    |
| DI1604 DI1605 DI0105 DI1604   DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 DI1604 |
```

Example of a model in the link:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QVaPfMHkY_QQQmcUrBgTLNCDwmbuwq98?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the modified DAX Measure

```
_Measure =
VAR _1 =
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            Table_1,
            "new", SUBSTITUTE ( Table_1[Calculated column], " ", "|" )
        ),
        [new] <> BLANK ()
    )
VAR _2 =
    GENERATE (
        _1,
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [new] ) ),
            "_txt", TRIM ( PATHITEM ( [new], [Value], TEXT ) )
        )
    )
VAR _filt =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _2,
        "score",
            VAR _1 = [_txt]
            VAR _2 =
                CALCULATE ( MAX ( table_2[List] ), TREATAS ( { _1 }, table_2[List] ) )
            RETURN
                IF ( _2 = BLANK (), "x", _2 )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        COUNTX ( FILTER ( _filt, [score] = "x" ), [Calculated column] ) >= 1,
        TRUE,
        FALSE
    )
```

Comment: This is great, thanks very much for your support. Additionally, this will help me understand how to approach the calculated columns and measures.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with **Power Query**, you can create a new table using this below **Advanced Query** code-

```
let
    Source = Table_1,
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Calculated Column", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Trimmed Text",{{"Calculated Column", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Calculated Column"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "Calculated Column"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Reordered Columns", {{"Calculated Column", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Calculated Column"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Calculated Column", type text}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Calculated Column"}, Table2, {"List  "}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"List  "}, {"Table2.List  "}),
    #"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Table2",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Sorted Rows1",{{"Table2.List  ", "Table2.List"}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Index"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table [Index=number, Calculated   Column=nullable text, #"Table2.List  "=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each [AllData][Calculated Column]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " "), type text}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom.1", each [AllData][Table2.List]),
    #"Extracted Values1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Custom.1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " "), type text}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Values1", "Custom.2", each if Text.Length([Custom.1]) = 0 then false else true),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Index", "AllData", "Custom.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom", "Calculated Column"}, {"Custom.2", "Is_present"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1"
```

Output will be as below-

[image]

**Now** you can join your **Table_1** and **Table_1_new** using **Calculated Column** and import **Is_present** from the new table for your further purpose.

Comment: Hi, this is a very interesting approach but I'm not able to get the desired result. When I'm applying your code it comes out with the following error:

Expression.Error: The column 'Calculated Column' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Calculated Column

In my model, the calculated column is a result of a measure. I wasn't aware that I can convert it into a table in a power query. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. What I have done is I have created a blank query and paste your code into it. Is that the correct method or should I do it in a different way?

Comment: I thought your "Calculated Column" is a column. As its measure, to make this code work, you can create the column in Excel before you import it to PBI. Or you can create Column instead of measure using the same logic in PBI. Creating blank query and paste the code is the right approach any way :)